# Saving text from CkEditor local on disk

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

Is there a way to save CKEditor (text) data as a textfile local on a disk so one can open it later and proceed with editing ? Just like wordprocessors do ?

Comment: Only when using server to write file. Javascript has no direct file access

Comment: @charlietfl: modern browsers have a built-in webserver. No need (other than fallback) to use a webserver to offer a download-link.. Probably a base64 data-url will also work as intermediate fallback for recent browsers.

Comment: @GitaarLAB _"modern browsers have a built-in webserver"_ Can describe details ?, links to documentations ?

Comment: @guest271314: Giving a good answer is a bit beyond the scope and space for a comment. Google `URL Store`. It is effectively a local/private mini webserver (including status-codes for XMLHttpRequest) serving any kind of binary or data, links are valid during session only. Also see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Using_object_URLs and http://stackoverflow.com/a/20537822/588079

Comment: @GitaarLAB Perhaps interpreted "modern browsers have a built-in webserver" technically , literally, here:)  see also http://help.opera.com/Windows/12.10/en/unite.html , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053244/is-it-possible-to-embed-a-http-server-in-a-google-chrome-extension , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240524/what-are-the-differences-between-opera-unite-and-node-js , http://serverfault.com/questions/212086/how-does-opera-unite-setup-a-web-server-without-port-forwarding

Comment: @guest271314: cool, didn't know that (all-tough a bit off-topic to the Q at hand). There is off-course a big difference here, the URL Store is not accessable outside the browser (as in, someone else even within the same network or computer can not access it (at least.. thats what I believe)). The links you shared are intended to turn the browser into a 'full' webserver that can be accessed by other users/browsers.

Comment: @GitaarLAB Yes ; initially , here , interpreted "modern browsers have a built-in webserver." _literally_ :) Cheers

Comment: @guest271314 Lol, the accompanying answer below would probably have cleared up what I was talking about, but it's week-end over here too `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Since the [FileSaver interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/#the-filesaver-interface) is not going to survive, why not use the browser's built-in webserver?
<sup>(Even if you have hosting, why make that hosting-company rich by wasting data-transfer paid from your (boss') money.. Don't like 'greed', then think of the environment: traffic==electricity... Don't like the environment, then argue security: 'why ship the user's potentially private content over the net, twice')</sup>

Here is an example to get you started:

```js
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;  //fallback for older prefixed objects

function update_download_lnk(str, elm){
  if(str){
    elm.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(  new Blob( [str], {type: 'text/plain'} )  );
    elm.style.display='';
  } else {
    elm.style.display='none';
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea onchange="update_download_lnk(this.value, this.nextSibling);"
></textarea><a href="#" style="display:none">Download File (right-click save-as..)</a>
```

Some [further reading here](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/06/Don-t-Build-Blobs-Construct-Them).

NOTE: smaller files can also be offered as base64 encoded dataURL.